# Get elasticsearch data by scrollId in different requests

Tags: java, elasticsearch, scroll, pagination

I'm using elasticsearch with Java API to get data using the scroll approach and since I have a lot of data I am trying to paginate the data by scrollId using multiple and subsequent requests.

Example:

Instead of:
`POST http://localhost:8080/country`

Returning this:

```
[
  {
    scrollId: abc,
    data: [{country: brazil}, {country: argentina}]
  },
  {
    scrollId: def,
    data: [{country: france}, {country: germany}]
  }
]
```

I would like to use:
`POST http://localhost:8080/country?paged=true`

With the first scrollId at the response:

```
{
  nextScrollId: abc
}
```

Then I can perform some requests while `nextScrollId` exists:

`POST http://localhost:8080/country?scrollId=abc`

Returning:

```
{
  nextScrollId: def,
  data: [{country: brazil}, {country: argentina}] //data from the "abc" scrollId
}
```

Then:
`POST http://.../data?scrollId=def`

Returning:

```
{
  nextScrollId: "", //no more results in this case
  data: [{country: france}, {country: germany}] //data from the "def" scrollId
}
```

Currently i am using this piece of code:

```
SearchResponse scrollResponse = elastic.getDataFromElasticSearch();

boolean hasNext = true;
String scrollId = request.getScrollId();
CountryResponse countryResponse = new CountryResponse();

do {
  if (scrollResponse.getScrollId().equals(scrollId)) {

    scrollResponse = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollId)
                      .setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1))
                      .execute()
                      .actionGet();

    //here i get the data from scrollResponse.getHits().getHits() 
    //and format it to that nextScrollId | data structure
    countryResponse.addCountriesFromElasticSearchResponse(scrollResponse);
  } else {
    hasNext = false;
  }

} while (hasNext == true);

countryResponse.setNextScrollId(scrollResponse.getScrollId());
return countryResponse;
```

With this, I can return the next scrollId properly.

The thing here is that whenever I try to get the data preparing the scroll with the nextScrollId, I got no data at the response.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

The scroll API is intended to be consumed by a single thread in one way.
Internally it creates a cursor which moves only forward thru search result where each call changes cursor state and it is impossible to repeat the same call two times for the same cursor(scroll).

In your case the problem is in understanding how scroll works internally - the first page can be obtained only by the first call:

[image]

In order to implement custom logic(described in question) with shifted iterator

[image]

you have to cache search results in case of the first request and keep(cache) them on your server with "your own iterator" shifted to original elastic iterator. Also keep in mind that:

- it is impossible to call one iterator two times
- iterator may expire
- how to scale you service? In case of few nodes of your service you have to route requests for the same session to the same node(sticky session). Elastic has it's own routing service and it works out-of-the-box.

So I am strongly recommend to use an [elastic scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html) in the way described in documentation.